# Does not name a type C++ error in code blocks

Tags: c++

```
#include <vector.h>
#include "UpdaterOptions.h"

struct VioManagerOptions {

        std::vector<int> matrix_wh = {752,480};
        matrix_wh.at(0) /= (params.downsample_cameras) ? 2.0 : 1.0;
        matrix_wh.at(1) /= (params.downsample_cameras) ? 2.0 : 1.0;
        std::pair<int,int> wh(matrix_wh.at(0),matrix_wh.at(1));

        UpdaterOptions msckf_options;
        msckf_options.sigma_pix = 1.0;//up_msckf_sigma_px;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    VioManagerOptions params;

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting error:

> msckf_options does not name a type
>
> matrix_wh does not name a type.

I am using codeblocks 16 in ubuntu xenial xeros

Comment: Please copy and paste the code and the error rather than using a screenshot.

Comment: The same is happening to T_CtoI..

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates your problem. Because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Comment: Your image is too small for old people like me to be able to see it

Comment: I have updated it .

Comment: @usmanarif What's with all that code in `VioManagerOptions`? Executable code must be in functions. Class scope can only contain declarations/definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit guessing what your intentions are, but maybe the code below looks like your intended program.

Within a struct one can declare data and functions. You did neither; your struct contains a function body. I've added a function name (member_function) to fix that. The error messages you got assumed that they were parsing data definitions, and your compiler complains that msckf_options and matrix_wh are no data types. All together, I would expect a lot more error messages than only these two.

Note <vector> i.s.o. <vector.h>.

Note also adding downsample_cameras as a member, and using it directly i.s.o. params.downsample_cameras.

Note dividing by integral values 2 and 1 i.s.o. doubles 2.0 and 1.0, since the data in the vector is also integral.

```
#include <vector>
#include "UpdaterOptions.h"

struct VioManagerOptions {

    void member_function()
    {
        std::vector<int> matrix_wh = { 752,480 };
        matrix_wh.at(0) /= (downsample_cameras) ? 2 : 1;
        matrix_wh.at(1) /= (downsample_cameras) ? 2 : 1;
        std::pair<int, int> wh(matrix_wh.at(0), matrix_wh.at(1));

        UpdaterOptions msckf_options;
        msckf_options.sigma_pix = 1.0;//up_msckf_sigma_px;
    }
    bool downsample_cameras;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    VioManagerOptions params;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your example is not calling the `member_function()`. It would make more sense to turn it into a constructor instead.